# Istio passthrough for external services doesn't work

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, istio, ingress-nginx

I am using outboundTrafficPolicy.mode ALLOW_ANY global option in Istio but any HTTPS requests are failing with a server certificate error:

```
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=*.execute-api.<my-region>.amazonaws.com
*  start date: Jul 22 00:00:00 2021 GMT
*  expire date: Aug 20 23:59:59 2022 GMT
*  subjectAltName does not match www.google.com
* SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'www.google.com'
* Closing connection 0
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, close notify (256):
curl: (60) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'www.google.com'
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html
```

Shouldn't it bypass all outbound traffic HTTP or HTTPS? Is there another configuration I'm missing here?

PS: I am using Istio with ingress-nginx with the `traffic.sidecar.istio.io/includeInboundPorts: ""` annotation, which bypasses envoy in the cluster's entrance. The test was made in another pod inside the service mesh.

**Istio configuration**: istioctl install --set profile=minimal --set meshConfig.outboundTrafficPolicy.mode=ALLOW_ANY --set meshConfig.enableTracing=true --set revision=canary

**Ingress-Nginx configuration**:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: IngressClass
metadata:
  name: nginx-4
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  annotations:
    ingressclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: 'false'
spec:
  controller: "k8s.io/ingress-nginx"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-4
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx-4
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx-4
    istio.io/rev: canary
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/controller-serviceaccount.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.33.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx-4
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx-4
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.47.0
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx-4
automountServiceAccountToken: true
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/controller-configmap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.33.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx-4
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx-4
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.47.0
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx-4
data:
  proxy-real-ip-cidr: <my_cluster_range>
  use-forwarded-headers: "true"
  enable-real-ip: "false"
  use-proxy-protocol: "false"
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/clusterrolebinding.yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.33.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx-4
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx-4
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.47.0
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  name: ingress-nginx-4
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: ingress-nginx
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: ingress-nginx
    namespace: ingress-nginx-4
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/controller-role.yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.33.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx-4
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx-4
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.47.0
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx-4
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ''
    resources:
      - namespaces
    verbs:
      - get
  - apiGroups:
      - ''
    resources:
      - configmaps
      - pods
      - secrets
      - endpoints
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - ''
    resources:
      - services
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - extensions
      - networking.k8s.io   # k8s 1.14+
    resources:
      - ingresses
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - extensions
      - networking.k8s.io   # k8s 1.14+
    resources:
      - ingresses/status
    verbs:
      - update
  - apiGroups:
      - networking.k8s.io   # k8s 1.14+
    resources:
      - ingressclasses
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - ''
    resources:
      - configmaps
    resourceNames:
      - ingress-controller-leader-nginx
    verbs:
      - get
      - update
  - apiGroups:
      - ''
    resources:
      - configmaps
    verbs:
      - create
      - update
  - apiGroups:
      - ''
    resources:
      - events
    verbs:
      - create
      - patch
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/controller-rolebinding.yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.33.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx-4
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx-4
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.47.0
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx-4
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: ingress-nginx
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: ingress-nginx
    namespace: ingress-nginx-4
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/controller-service-webhook.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.33.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx-4
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx-4
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.47.0
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app: ingress-nginx-4
  name: ingress-nginx-controller-admission
  namespace: ingress-nginx-4
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - name: https-webhook
      port: 443
      targetPort: webhook
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx-4
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx-4
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app: ingress-nginx-4
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/controller-service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: http
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-connection-idle-timeout: '60'
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-cross-zone-load-balancing-enabled: 'true'
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.33.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx-4
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx-4
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.47.0
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app: ingress-nginx-4
    service: ingress-nginx-4
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx-4
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      nodePort: 30008
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: http
    - name: https
      port: 443
      nodePort: 30009
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: http
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx-4
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx-4
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app: ingress-nginx-4
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/controller-deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.33.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx-4
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx-4
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.47.0
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app: ingress-nginx-4
    version: v1
  name: ingress-nginx-controller-2
  namespace: ingress-nginx-4
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx-4
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx-4
      app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
      app: ingress-nginx-4
      version: v1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  minReadySeconds: 0
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
        prometheus.io/port: "10254"
        sidecar.istio.io/inject: "true"
        traffic.sidecar.istio.io/includeInboundPorts: ""
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx-4
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx-4
        app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
        app: ingress-nginx-4
        version: v1
    spec:
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      containers:
        - name: controller
          image: k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/controller:v0.46.0@sha256:52f0058bed0a17ab0fb35628ba97e8d52b5d32299fbc03cc0f6c7b9ff036b61a
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          lifecycle:
            preStop:
              exec:
                command:
                  - /wait-shutdown
          args:
            - /nginx-ingress-controller
            - --publish-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx-controller
            - --election-id=ingress-controller-leader
            - --ingress-class=nginx-4
            - --configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx-controller
            - --validating-webhook=:8443
            - --validating-webhook-certificate=/usr/local/certificates/cert
            - --validating-webhook-key=/usr/local/certificates/key
          securityContext:
            capabilities:
              drop:
                - ALL
              add:
                - NET_BIND_SERVICE
            runAsUser: 101
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
          env:
            - name: POD_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
            - name: POD_NAMESPACE
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.namespace
            - name: LD_PRELOAD
              value: /usr/local/lib/libmimalloc.so
          livenessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 5
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 10254
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 1
          readinessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 3
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 10254
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 1
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
            - name: https
              containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
            - name: tohttps
              containerPort: 2443
              protocol: TCP
            - name: webhook
              containerPort: 8443
              protocol: TCP
          volumeMounts:
            - name: webhook-cert
              mountPath: /usr/local/certificates/
              readOnly: true
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 90Mi
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/os: linux
      serviceAccountName: ingress-nginx
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 300
      volumes:
        - name: webhook-cert
          secret:
            secretName: ingress-nginx-admission
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/admission-webhooks/validating-webhook.yaml
# before changing this value, check the required kubernetes version
# https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/extensible-admission-controllers/#prerequisites
apiVersion: admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1
kind: ValidatingWebhookConfiguration
metadata:
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.33.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx-4
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx-4
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.47.0
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
  name: ingress-nginx-admission-4
webhooks:
  - name: validate.nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io
    matchPolicy: Equivalent
    rules:
      - apiGroups:
          - networking.k8s.io
        apiVersions:
          - v1beta1
        operations:
          - CREATE
          - UPDATE
        resources:
          - ingresses
    failurePolicy: Fail
    sideEffects: None
    admissionReviewVersions:
      - v1
      - v1beta1
    clientConfig:
      service:
        namespace: ingress-nginx-4
        name: ingress-nginx-controller-admission
        path: /networking/v1beta1/ingresses
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/admission-webhooks/job-patch/serviceaccount.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-admission
  annotations:
    helm.sh/hook: pre-install,pre-upgrade,post-install,post-upgrade
    helm.sh/hook-delete-policy: before-hook-creation,hook-succeeded
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.33.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx-4
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx-4
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.47.0
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
  namespace: ingress-nginx-4
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/admission-webhooks/job-patch/clusterrolebinding.yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-admission-4
  annotations:
    helm.sh/hook: pre-install,pre-upgrade,post-install,post-upgrade
    helm.sh/hook-delete-policy: before-hook-creation,hook-succeeded
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.33.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx-4
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx-4
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.47.0
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: ingress-nginx-admission
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: ingress-nginx-admission
    namespace: ingress-nginx-4
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/admission-webhooks/job-patch/role.yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-admission
  annotations:
    helm.sh/hook: pre-install,pre-upgrade,post-install,post-upgrade
    helm.sh/hook-delete-policy: before-hook-creation,hook-succeeded
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.33.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx-4
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx-4
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.47.0
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
  namespace: ingress-nginx-4
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ''
    resources:
      - secrets
    verbs:
      - get
      - create
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/admission-webhooks/job-patch/rolebinding.yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-admission
  annotations:
    helm.sh/hook: pre-install,pre-upgrade,post-install,post-upgrade
    helm.sh/hook-delete-policy: before-hook-creation,hook-succeeded
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.33.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx-4
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx-4
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.47.0
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
  namespace: ingress-nginx-4
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: ingress-nginx-admission
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: ingress-nginx-admission
    namespace: ingress-nginx-4
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/admission-webhooks/job-patch/job-createSecret.yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-admission-create
  annotations:
    helm.sh/hook: pre-install,pre-upgrade
    helm.sh/hook-delete-policy: before-hook-creation,hook-succeeded
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.33.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx-4
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx-4
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.47.0
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
  namespace: ingress-nginx-4
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: ingress-nginx-admission-create
      labels:
        helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.33.0
        app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx-4
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx-4
        app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.47.0
        app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
        app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: create
          image: docker.io/jettech/kube-webhook-certgen:v1.5.1
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          args:
            - create
            - --host=ingress-nginx-controller-admission,ingress-nginx-controller-admission.$(POD_NAMESPACE).svc
            - --namespace=$(POD_NAMESPACE)
            - --secret-name=ingress-nginx-admission
          env:
            - name: POD_NAMESPACE
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.namespace
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
      serviceAccountName: ingress-nginx-admission
      securityContext:
        runAsNonRoot: true
        runAsUser: 2000
---
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/admission-webhooks/job-patch/job-patchWebhook.yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-admission-patch
  annotations:
    helm.sh/hook: post-install,post-upgrade
    helm.sh/hook-delete-policy: before-hook-creation,hook-succeeded
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.33.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx-4
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx-4
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.47.0
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
  namespace: ingress-nginx-4
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: ingress-nginx-admission-patch
      labels:
        helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.33.0
        app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx-4
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx-4
        app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.47.0
        app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
        app.kubernetes.io/component: admission-webhook
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: patch
          image: docker.io/jettech/kube-webhook-certgen:v1.5.1
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          args:
            - patch
            - --webhook-name=ingress-nginx-admission-4
            - --namespace=$(POD_NAMESPACE)
            - --patch-mutating=false
            - --secret-name=ingress-nginx-admission
            - --patch-failure-policy=Fail
          env:
            - name: POD_NAMESPACE
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.namespace
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
      serviceAccountName: ingress-nginx-admission
      securityContext:
        runAsNonRoot: true
        runAsUser: 2000
```

Comment: Can you please share more information about your issue? Please share your ingress-nginx and Istio configurations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by what probably is a bug on Istio: services on the Kubernetes cluster that had 443 ports (https) and didn't contain a port name as "https" seemed to be getting in the way of external https requests.
To solve the issue I just identified these services using the `istioctl proxy-config routes <my-pod> --name 443 -o json` command and added the "https" port name.
I also deleted a ServiceEntry from a previous Istio version that was also impacting routing.

Istio issue comment that helped me identify the problem: https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/14264#issuecomment-496774533